# AnimationUtils.loadAnimation is crashing the app

Tags: android, animation, animationutils

I m building an app that uses AnimationUtils.loadAnimation to move imageviews based on an anim xml.
The app has 2 activities. The first (MainActivity) loads and plays the animation normally. The second activity implements a SurfaceHolder.Callback and crashes when it tries to load the animation .
Here is the code (inside onCreate):

```
ImageView sonar_line = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sonar_line);
animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.radar_line_slow);

sonar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
                if(sonar_line==null){
                    sonar_line = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sonar_line);
                }
                sonar_line.startAnimation(animation2);
    });
```

Could the problem be the SurfaceHolder.Callback ? Please help.

Here is the logcat :

```
08-16 12:30:55.280: I/Choreographer(907): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-16 12:30:56.742: I/Choreographer(907): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-16 12:30:57.690: I/Ads(907): Received ad url: <url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=1&session_id=4668883432257618371&seq_num=2&u_w=598&msid=com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector&cap=m%2Ca&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1&bas_off=0&imbf=8008&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector&hl=en&gnt=3&carrier=310260&u_audio=4&kw&u_sd=2&ms=d_7Bq5TdKAYUPAq5seYPrZArBEIpPihNvTTeNQDAEv8YyBIlIZh5YbQplCb16O6hO40chh2qUW8t1tJdM_Y0-Ari8v_1TdDZzaXn22PCXxjuzmIP85qR7clhmZsisJR90_zD7qFPxhxLvzLSgoki41A0OkB2v8uWb0XTkcbhZH5G-qXseDQAgb99cPtkGZcABevehjoN1pbbr_NBnh_lnb5x7y9gSyca3Vd0Ic6TFh3LC3ot8eLIaxZqfKPJDXDPyJhADKAMGOYIZvnIQagFp6chf8g2RKzuOcDCxbsOLmA4ePyVJiIPsaSzTN6K63Z9mJ_sgbSWeOGM7mzUsafwCg&format=320x50_mb&oar=0&u_h=360&bas_on=0&ptime=52008&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a1520cd4827f988&kw_type=broad&askip=1&gsb=3g&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&eisu=uwwmiYREuXHN4MUb9Hax3DDGURdO_nWguot6OCV-e2efBzDgOa3ojiKuUNuWJUlJvB88tkDZKxo7-1zOQhLTfDNGDzto9vFYrbSFJtUdAOvefYgfHc5tm0oEhvilr9TB&et=360&jsv=53" type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null" activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
08-16 12:30:57.711: I/Ads(907): Request scenario: Online server request.
08-16 12:31:00.770: I/Choreographer(907): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-16 12:31:02.990: I/Choreographer(907): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-16 12:31:04.502: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5441K, 14% free 36967K/42904K, paused 136ms, total 180ms
08-16 12:31:04.601: I/dalvikvm-heap(907): Grow heap (frag case) to 40.028MB for 4000016-byte allocation
08-16 12:31:05.081: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_CONCURRENT freed 84K, 5% free 40789K/42904K, paused 148ms+50ms, total 479ms
08-16 12:31:05.081: D/dalvikvm(907): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 279ms
08-16 12:31:05.521: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 977K, 7% free 40144K/42904K, paused 138ms, total 139ms
08-16 12:31:05.521: I/dalvikvm-heap(907): Grow heap (frag case) to 40.355MB for 1089936-byte allocation
08-16 12:31:05.761: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 41208K/43972K, paused 131ms, total 132ms
08-16 12:31:05.792: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
08-16 12:31:05.831: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.mreprogramming.ultimateentitydetector.Cam_View$4.onClick(Cam_View.java:198)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-16 12:31:05.931: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you also put your logcat errors ?

Comment: You are getting nullpointer at line no. 198

Comment: I'm guessing `sonar_line` is null, rather than `animation2`. If `animation2` were null, you'd get an NPE *inside* `startAnimation`. Where are you assigning a value to `sonar_line`?

Comment: I added the findViewById

Comment: Check if sonar_line is null. Try something like this: `if(sonar_line == null) Log.e("sonar_line","null");` after initializing the ImageView.

Comment: I see. Try to debug some more. Place a breakpoint inside `onClick` on that offending `startAnimation` line, launch your application (in debug mode) and click `sonar`. The debugger should hit the breakpoint and show you all sorts of interesting runtime information. Check the values of `sonar_line` and `animation2` at that point, making sure they're not `null`.

Comment: I edited my post adding an if statement to check for null but it didnt fix it

Comment: @MattiasBuelens how do i add a breakpoint ?

Comment: Did you get an output in your logcat with `if(sonar_line == null) Log.e("sonar_line","null");`? If not, try the same with your animation2.

Comment: @mremremre1 That depends on the IDE you're developing in (Eclipse, Android Studio,...). Most of the time, you'd click to the left of the line number in the code editor. It should show an icon to indicate that there's a breakpoint on that line (e.g. a red circle). Try Googling for something like `(your IDE) add breakpoint`.

Comment: Guys i found it . The mistake was stupid. When i was creating the second layout xml based on the first the ImageView soner_line was not copied and pasted. Thanks everyone and sorry for wasting your time :D

Comment: @mremremre1 Classic. I suggest you learn how to properly debug a program, so you can quickly find these issues yourself. Place breakpoints, step through the code, watch how the variables change and spot the oddities. In this case, you'd quickly notice that `sonar_line` was *still* `null` immediately after the `findViewById` call, which should alert you that you may be missing a view or using the wrong ID.